# CSS Transition not working in table colgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Transition doesn't work when colgroup width changes.

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  if ($('table col').hasClass("expanded"))
    $('table col').removeClass('expanded');
  else
    $('table col').addClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table col {
  -webkit-transition: width .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .8s ease;
  -o-transition: width .8s ease;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}
.expanded {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">Button</button>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I was using this code. In this code THE CSS Transition property will not work. `transition: width .8s ease;`

Comment: It works when a width is given to `table col` without the class `expanded` http://front-back.com/css-transition-from-a-fixed-px-width-to-an-auto-width

Answer (score 3):

A CSS transition needs to be able to calculate the difference between the starting point and the ending point to be able to *transition* it. If no width is given then the width will default to `auto`, from `auto` you cannot animate to a fixed value like `200px` because `auto` can be anything.

Applying a basic `width` property to the `table col` selector with a default value of `100px` solves the issue because now the browser understands what it is you want to do.

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  if ($('table col').hasClass("expanded"))
    $('table col').removeClass('expanded');
  else
    $('table col').addClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table col {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .8s ease;
  -o-transition: width .8s ease;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}
.expanded {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">Button</button>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is to use a `min-width` property.

Since a transition needs a fixed value to work, give `width: 0px;` and `min-width: auto;` to your element, and because `min-width` properties are more important than `width`, your element looks the same, and your transition *smooothly* runs.

```
table col {
    min-width: auto;
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: width .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vff7yyu/1/)!

Comment: Do you mean without setting width at all? Or without setting width specifically to `<colgroup>`?

Comment: You actually don't need a <colgroup> tag here. You could for example apply the transition on the <th> tag. See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vff7yyu/2/

Comment: actually i'm changing width dynamically that's why i m using colgroup..so only..need solution without setting width in colgroup

Comment: You would need a more detailed example here if you want some further help!

Comment: Kudos for this solution, massive +1 for detailing `width` vs `min-width`, that's a neat trick indeed, I wonder how cross-browser it is :)